# capture content of div as image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I want to capture the div as an image after the image is adjusted with zoom and drag within the div.

I am using this plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/Smart-jQuery-Pan-Zoom-Plugin-Smart-jQuery-Zoom.html to pan and zoom the image, within the div and http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ this plugin to convert the div into image.

**htmlfile.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="e-smart-zoom-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#imgContainer {
width: 980px;
height: 500px;
}

.zoomableContainer {
background-image: url("assets/transparent.png");
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="pageContent">
<div id="imgContainer"> <img id="imageFullScreen" src="assets/zoomFullScreen.jpg"/> </div>
</div>
<button onclick="capture()">capture</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#imageFullScreen').smartZoom({'containerClass':'zoomableContainer'});

function moveButtonClickHandler(e){
var pixelsToMoveOnX = 0;
var pixelsToMoveOnY = 0;

switch(e.target.id){
case "leftPositionMap":
pixelsToMoveOnX = 50;
break;
case "rightPositionMap":
pixelsToMoveOnX = -50;
break;
case "topPositionMap":
pixelsToMoveOnY = 50;
break;
case "bottomPositionMap":
pixelsToMoveOnY = -50;
break;
}
$('#imageFullScreen').smartZoom('pan', pixelsToMoveOnX, pixelsToMoveOnY);
    }

});


function capture(){
    var ele = document.getElementById("pageContent");
    html2canvas(ele, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I am not getting the output as required.

Here is the screenshot of the page when page is loaded.

[image: page load]

Here is the screenshot of the page after doing drag and zoom

[image: zoomed image]

And here is the result which is generated after clicking on the capture button

[image]

Here is the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/knkbsvy2/

Comment: is this live somewhere or can we get a fiddle?

Comment: It's a localhost project with external plugins

Comment: I don't know what to tell you man, you may get lucky with someone knowing exactly what the problem is or you could put together a fiddle so that everyone can debug it for you

Comment: Here is the fiddle @SergChernata https://jsfiddle.net/knkbsvy2/

Comment: i actually can't even get the fiddle to get as far as you say it does

Comment: +1 question got the same one! only I am needing to copy a element then open the screen shot into a new tab for saving.

Comment: fiddle don't work